# How to create roles and permissions in laravel-permission when moving to new enviornments?

Tags: laravel

I use laravel-permission to create roles and to assign permissions as mentioned in here. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission. Permissions in my system are more static, once you create a permission for example to allow update blog posts to admin, it can't be changed by users or anyone outside.

But problem comes when I want to move my system into another environment, rollback my changes or if I want to share my code with another colleague. Then again he has to run all the new permission create, delete, assign commands. I followed two practices in here,

1. Keep a file of artisan commands to update/edit permissions, so whenever I move this system to somewhere else I have to run them.
2. Create another route and use it to update/edit permissions.

But while i'm working on this, it doesn't feel a good way to do. Are there any best practices to follow in this situation built into laravel-permission (similar to a database migration) or any other custom practice?

Comment: Put them in either a migration (if they should *always* be present in a new install) or a seeder (if you want them to be optional on the part of whoever's working with the codebase).

Comment: You mean to add the laravel permission create codes "$role->givePermissionTo($permission);" like this in database migration scripts?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **Laravel Database Seeders** for something like this.

You can create a seeder with this command-

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

Laravel seeders allow you to feed some initial data in your tables. So when you are sharing your code with other people, they would run this command to seed the data-

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Just for a quick idea, you can do something like this in a seeder class-

```
 $add = Permission::create(['name' => 'account.add', 'display_name' => 'Access to account add functionality']);
 $edit = Permission::create(['name' => 'account.edit', 'display_name' => 'Access to account edit functionality']);

 Role::findByName('admin')->givePermissionTo($add);
 Role::findByName('manager')->givePermissionTo($edit);
```

Above code is a sample on how you can give permission to a role by finding it by its name.

Comment: I believe Laravel 5.7 was released at the time of this answer. Laravel's documentation has characterized seeding as something that's meant for temporary test data, not data that's formally required by the application and meant to persist to production: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding